# Average of non zeros for arrays in visual basics

Tags: arrays, vba, average, standard-deviation

I have an array with 2000 elements in that I would like to calculate the average and standard deviation of non zero elements.
Here is my code:

```
Function CI(Column_In As Integer, Row_Out As Integer, Column_Out As String)

Dim Arr() As Integer
N_of_P = 2000
ReDim Arr(N_of_P)

   For i = 3 To N_of_P
   Arr(i) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, Column_In).Value
   Next i

   With Application.WorksheetFunction

   DAverage = .Averageif(Arr, "Arr <> "0") ' this causes the error!
   dStdDev = .StDev(Arr) ' do we have standard deviation if function?

   End With
```

Comment: 1 a function called from a worksheet cannot effect another cell, so this would be better as a sub not a function.  2. I do not believe you can use an array in a worksheetfunction, Just use `.Averageif(Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(3,Column_In),Worksheets(1).Cells(N_of_P,Column_In)),"<>0")`

Comment: 3. no there is no StDevIf() function.  Use `Evaluate("STDEV(IF(" & Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(3,Column_‌​In),Worksheets(1).Ce‌​lls(N_of_P,Column_In‌​)).Address(0,0) & "<>0," & Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(3,Column_‌​In),Worksheets(1).Ce‌​lls(N_of_P,Column_In‌​)).Address(0,0) & "))")`

Comment: @ScottCraner the error is "unable to get the average property of the worksheetfunction class vba runtime error 1004" when I run the average code.